# Imagen PNG como borde en CSS

Tags: html, css

Básicamente tengo que conseguir lo que muestra resultado.jpg pero no consigo meter la imagen movil.png como borde.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El ejercicio me pide esto:

> En los elementos `<article>` debes conseguir el efecto que se muestra en la imagen resultado.jpg utilizando la imagen móvil.png para los bordes
> (ambas imágenes están en el fichero recursos.zip). Ten en cuenta que
> también deberás modificar los márgenes de los elementos.

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

html {
    background-color: white;
}

body {
    padding-top: 20px; 
    text-align: center;
    background: linear-gradient(orangered, orange);
}

#page {
    width: 960px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: left;
}

header {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    border-bottom: 6px solid black;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0170B9, #27AADE);
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
}

h1 {
    background-image: url("../imgs/logo.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 25px center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 100px;
}

nav {
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background: linear-gradient(#d5ba32, #ffda3e);
}

li {
   padding-top: 80px; 
   margin-top: 0px;
   margin-right: 100px;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   margin-left: 100px;
   list-style-type: none;
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
   cursor: default;
}

#contenidos {
    background-image: url("../imgs/book.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-position-y: 10px;

}

#videos {
    background-image: url("../imgs/film.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-position-y: 10px;
}

#contacto {
    background-image: url("../imgs/mail.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-position-y: 10px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

a:hover {
    color: orange;
}

#content {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    background-color: white;
}

.article {
    width: 240px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    padding: 5px 5px 22px 5px;
    margin: 30px;
    float:left;
    border-image-source: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/iscHd.png");
    border-image-slice: 10 fill;
    min-height:504px
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after,

#content {
    width:100%;
    display: table;
}

.article_header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
}

h2 {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

footer {
    color: white;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    text-align: center;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #0170B9, #27AADE);
    border-top: 6px solid black;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}

footer a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Curso de HTML5 y CSS3</title>
  <meta name="description" content="HTML5, CSS3">
  <meta name="author" content="Prueba">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="page">
    
        <header>
            <h1>Curso de HTML5 y CSS3</h1>
        </header>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li id="contenidos">Contenidos</li>
                <li id="videos"><a href="#">Vídeos</a></li>
                <li id="contacto"><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div id="content">
            <div class="article">
                <div class="article_header">
                    <img src="imgs/html5.png" alt="HTML5">
                    <h2>HTML5</h2>
                </div>
                <p>
                    Veremos los nuevos <strong>elementos estructurales</strong>, así como los nuevos elementos existentes para <strong>formularios, audio y vídeo</strong>.
                </p>
                <p>
                     El <strong>nuevo elemento canvas</strong> nos abre un mundo de posibilidades en el <strong>desarrollo de vídeojuegos</strong> web.
                </p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="article">
                <div class="article_header">
                    <img src="imgs/css3.png" alt="CSS3">
                    <h2>CSS3</h2>
                </div>
                <p>
                    Mejoraremos nuestros diseños web utilizando las nuevas características de CSS3: <strong>efectos, transformaciones, animaciones</strong>, etc. 
                </p>
                <p>
                    Con <strong>CSS3</strong> nuestros diseños serán más simples, pero no menos impactantes.
                </p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="article">
                <div class="article_header">
                    <img src="imgs/javascript.png" alt="Javascript">
                    <h2>Javascript</h2>
                </div>
                <p>
                    Junto con HTML5 aparecen nuevas <strong>API javascript</strong> que nos aportan multitud de facilidades y posibilidades en el desarrollo de nuestros proyectos web.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Con las nuevas API javascript nuestras manos dejarán de estar atadas.
                </p>
            </div>
            
        </div> <!-- content -->
        
        <footer>
              <p>Prueba © 2022. Curso de HTML5 y CSS3.</p>
              <p>Impartido para: <a href="http://cefire.edu.gva.es"> CEFIRE - Específico de Formación Profesional</a></p>
        </footer>
        
    </div> <!-- page -->
    
</body>
</html>
```

Básicamente no sé colocar la imagen móvil para que quede tal como la imagen.

[image: Lo unico que consigo es algo así, bastante lamentable lo sé jaj]

Lo único que consigo es algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes que colocar la imagen del móvil en un pregunta, para poder recrear el asunto

Comment: La he añadido en la publiacion no sé si te refieres a eso, soy nuevo

Comment: Si, así está bien y si pudieras colocar al menos una de las 3 imágenes de la cabecera (la que tiene los logos) también sería útil

Comment: Buff me he hecho un lioo añadiendo imagenes no sé si te sirve con algo como eso jajaja

Comment: jajaj si, lo único que borraste la primera imagen y ya no veo como tiene que quedar

Comment: Y ahora como la añado solo me deja añadir 8 jajaja

Comment: No importa, ya publiqué una respuesta, donde el primer móvil tiene imagen, este se lo tendrás que cambiar, es solo para que se pueda ver en la demo de esta página. Espero que te sirva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El único truco del asunto es jugar con los valores de border-image-slice y border-image-width hasta que quede una imagen proporcionada

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

html {
    background-color: white;
}

body {
    padding-top: 20px; 
    text-align: center;
    background: linear-gradient(orangered, orange);
}

#page {
    width: 960px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: left;
}

header {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    border-bottom: 6px solid black;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0170B9, #27AADE);
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
}

h1 {
    background-image: url("../imgs/logo.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 25px center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 100px;
}

nav {
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background: linear-gradient(#d5ba32, #ffda3e);
}

li {
   padding-top: 80px; 
   margin-top: 0px;
   margin-right: 100px;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   margin-left: 100px;
   list-style-type: none;
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
   cursor: default;
}

#contenidos {
    background-image: url("../imgs/book.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-position-y: 10px;

}

#videos {
    background-image: url("../imgs/film.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-position-y: 10px;
}

#contacto {
    background-image: url("../imgs/mail.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-position-y: 10px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

a:hover {
    color: orange;
}

#content {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    background-color: white;
}

.article {
    width: 240px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    margin: 30px;
    float:left;
    border-image-source: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/iscHd.png");
    border-image-slice: 66;
    border-image-width: 66;
    min-height:504px
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after,

#content {
    width:100%;
    display: table;
}

.article_header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
    margin:55px 16px 0px 18px;
}
.article_header img{
  object-fit:cover;
  width:100%;
}
.article p{
    margin: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
line-height: 15px;
}
h2 {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

footer {
    color: white;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    text-align: center;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #0170B9, #27AADE);
    border-top: 6px solid black;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}

footer a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Curso de HTML5 y CSS3</title>
  <meta name="description" content="HTML5, CSS3">
  <meta name="author" content="Prueba">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="page">
    
        <header>
            <h1>Curso de HTML5 y CSS3</h1>
        </header>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li id="contenidos">Contenidos</li>
                <li id="videos"><a href="#">Vídeos</a></li>
                <li id="contacto"><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div id="content">
            <div class="article">
                <div class="article_header">
                    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZ8r1.png" alt="HTML5">
                    <h2>HTML5</h2>
                </div>
                <p>
                    Veremos los nuevos <strong>elementos estructurales</strong>, así como los nuevos elementos existentes para <strong>formularios, audio y vídeo</strong>.
                </p>
                <p>
                     El <strong>nuevo elemento canvas</strong> nos abre un mundo de posibilidades en el <strong>desarrollo de vídeojuegos</strong> web.
                </p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="article">
                <div class="article_header">
                    <img src="imgs/css3.png" alt="CSS3">
                    <h2>CSS3</h2>
                </div>
                <p>
                    Mejoraremos nuestros diseños web utilizando las nuevas características de CSS3: <strong>efectos, transformaciones, animaciones</strong>, etc. 
                </p>
                <p>
                    Con <strong>CSS3</strong> nuestros diseños serán más simples, pero no menos impactantes.
                </p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="article">
                <div class="article_header">
                    <img src="imgs/javascript.png" alt="Javascript">
                    <h2>Javascript</h2>
                </div>
                <p>
                    Junto con HTML5 aparecen nuevas <strong>API javascript</strong> que nos aportan multitud de facilidades y posibilidades en el desarrollo de nuestros proyectos web.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Con las nuevas API javascript nuestras manos dejarán de estar atadas.
                </p>
            </div>
            
        </div> <!-- content -->
        
        <footer>
              <p>Prueba © 2022. Curso de HTML5 y CSS3.</p>
              <p>Impartido para: <a href="http://cefire.edu.gva.es"> CEFIRE - Específico de Formación Profesional</a></p>
        </footer>
        
    </div> <!-- page -->
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias no sabes cuanto te lo agradezco que grande jajaja